# WatchOS InterfaceMap update user location on map

Tags: swift, mapkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-4

Anyone know how to show the "blue pulsating dot" for the user devices location on watchOS InterfaceMap element?

In iOS this can be done to MKMapView by calling mapView.showsUserLocation = true. InterfaceMap for watchOS doesn't seem to be supporting this and I was wondering if there is some other way to do this. Of course this could be done manually by placing an annotation on the user location every time the location is updated, but it seems a bit clunky and it would be great to have the default blue marker for the user location.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this on `watchOS`. `WKInterfaceMap` can only be used to show a static piece of the map at the moment. `WKInterfaceMap` shows a noninteractive map for a specific location. You can change the location shown on the map dynamically, but there are no built-in methods to update it automatically to show the user location in contrast to what `MKMapView` can achieve.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to show an interactive map on watchos? I did some furious google searching recently and found this app http://support.viewranger.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=188. They seem to have managed to show a mapView on their watch application. I wonder how they did it though.

Comment: You can build your own UI element mimicking `MKMapView`, but you cannot use a `WKInterfaceMap` for an interactive map, so I'm quite certain that's not what the linked app does either.

Comment: Any ideas how to create a custom view that would mimic a map without using the map that apple has provided for the watch? Drawing trails and annotations on a piece of a map image seems so difficult without the help of coordinates (if you cannot use a map element for it)